# Outlook.Exe Keeping Handle After Attachment Save VB

Tags: vba, outlook

I have some VBA that i use to download all the attachments from an email and save them to a directory.

This is causing me some problems because the handle from Outlook is remaining on the folder and as a result it fails to delete correctly.

I thought my code is pretty fool proof and shouldn't be keeping a hold on the folder after the completion of the script.

Can someone please point out to me what I have done wrong :/

```
Sub SaveCustDetails(myItem As Outlook.MailItem)

'On Error Resume Next

Dim myOlapp As Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim I As Long

Dim strBranch As String
Dim strPolRef As String
Dim strBody As String
Dim strBrLoc As Integer
Dim strPrLoc As Integer
Dim strFolderName As String

Set myOlapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNameSpace = myOlapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
'Set myFolder = myFolder.Folders("Crash Alerts")

'Places the Body in a string
strBody = myItem.Body

'Finds the Branch Number
strBrLoc = InStr(1, strBody, "Branch:")
strBranch = Mid(strBody, strBrLoc + 8, 1)

'Finds the Policy Reference
strPrLoc = InStr(1, strBody, "Reference:")
strPolRef = Mid(strBody, strPrLoc + 11, 10)

'Concatenate The Branch Number and PolRef
strFolderName = strBranch & "-" & strPolRef

    If myItem.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then

        For Each myAttachment In myItem.Attachments

            strAttachmentName = myAttachment.DisplayName

            strFindOBracket = InStr(4, strAttachmentName, "(") 'Finds the Bracket

            If strFindOBracket <> 0 Then
            strAttachment = Trim(Mid(strAttachmentName, 1, strFindOBracket - 1)) & ".pdf"
            Else
            strAttachment = myAttachment.DisplayName
            End If

            FilePath = "C:\Processing\HTML Email\" & strFolderName & "\"

            If Len(Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            MkDir FilePath
            End If

            If strAttachment = "Covernote.pdf" Then
            myAttachment.SaveAsFile FilePath & "Covernote1.pdf"
            Else
            myAttachment.SaveAsFile FilePath & strAttachment
            End If
            I = I + 1

        Next
    End If

'Next

Set myOlapp = Nothing
Set myNameSpace = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set myAttachment = Nothing
Set myItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What has this to do with VB.Net or VBScript? Where are you automating Outlook from?

Comment: I guess its flat VBA - I'm Automating from within Outlook itself. I have changed the labels accordingly. Apologies was typed in a rush.

Comment: If you are doing this from outlook-vba then why are you creating an Outlook instance?

Comment: Also since you are doing this from Outlook itself, there will always be one instance of Outlook in the task manager and will remain till you actually quit Outlook.

Comment: I'm not a VB Programmer - I just recycled some old code I found from a previous contractor we had in and manipulated what I could. Since I am calling from within Outlook then I guess I don't need the olApp as I'm not calling it externally?

Comment: I need Outlook to stay open as the code runs as part of a rule on message receive, I need it to download the attachments to a folder named accordingly and then release the folder. At present it doesn everything but doesn't release the handle on the folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41173/discussion-between-lynchie-and-siddharth-rout)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question myself after Siddharth's fantastic help and guidance Outlook isn't holding on to the directory.

The directory itself is a ghost directory that remains when it is deleted. This was causing my looping mechanism to fall over. The solution was code that Siddharth had provided me with:

```
On Error Resume Next
Kill FilePath & "*.*"
DoEvents
On Error GoTo 0

RmDir FilePath   
DoEvents

'This line then polls explorer again to confirm the deletion and 
'removes the ghost folder.
Debug.Print Len(Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory))
```

Again the help provided by Siddharth was absolutely fantastic I would give a thumbs up to any help he can provide.