# VBA moving folder using FSO keeps folder in use

Tags: vba, excel-2007, filesystemobject

I am using the below code to cycle through '.csv' files in a directory and move them to a new directory (strRootDir and strTargetDir are local variables that have been initiated):

```
Dim objFile As file
Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject:     Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject
Dim objFolder As Folder:            Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strRootDir)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

    If InStr(1, objFile.Name, ".csv") Then

        FileFolderExists strTargetDir, True
        objFile.Move (strTargetDir)

    End If

Next objFile

Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Where the method 'FileFolderExists' is defined as:

```
Public Sub FileFolderExists(strFullPath As String, bMkDir As Boolean)
    Dim bExists As Boolean
    If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then bExists = True
    If Not bExists And bMkDir Then MkDir strFullPath
End Sub
```

My question is that once this process has completed, if I try to delete the directory 'strTargetDir' I get an error message saying the folder is in use by another program.

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is a Ghost File. The explorer has an uncanny habit of being stubborn :)

Here is [another scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975143/outlook-exe-keeping-handle-after-attachment-save-vb) which illustrates the "Ghost File"

Just issue a `Dir` command to remind explorer that the file no longer exists after you move the file and every thing will be ok :)

```
Ret = Dir(Path_And_FileName_Which_Was_Moved)
```

Also why use fso for moving files? Here is a one line command

```
Name "C:\Path1\File1.Ext" As "C:\Path2\File2.Ext"
```

This will also not leave a GHOST File

Comment: Wow! thanks. Both methods worked great.  Timed them both and Name file1 as file2 is about 50% quicker.